# Xcode 7 supporting watch OS2 with iOS8 and iOS9 support

Tags: ios8, ios9, xcode7, apple-watch, watchos-2

Can I provide support with only watchOS2 app having iOS8 support ?

1. I am supporting iOS8 and iOS9 both in my iOS app.
2. I need to add watch app with WatchOS2.
3. User who installs in iOS9 devices are able to use watchOS2 app, but people who are using iOS8 app can't use my watch app, is this possible ?

I am confused at this point because I have to provide support for iOS8 and iOS9.
I need to take a decision quickly, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have iOS 9 for WatchOS 2 to work.
Once you update OS of your watch to Watch OS 2.0 and after it, if you try it to pair with iOS 8 version iPhone, then it will not work and Apple Watch app would advise you that your version of iOS is out of date. It would not allow you to proceed with pairing until you had updated your iPhone software to iOS 9 (Whatever latest version of iOS 9.0).

If you want to support Watch OS 1 and Watch OS 2 then you have to set separate target for both of them.

[image]

Comment: That's correct that user having watchOS2 also have to have iOS9 on devices, but I also need to support iOS8 for iOSApp, the user who install the app on iOS devices they cant access the watchOS2 app. I want to produce this situation.

Comment: You can add separate target for Watch OS 1 and Watch OS 2.

Comment: I don't want to allow watch OS1 app for the users who are using iOS8.
I want add WatchOS2 app only. So iOS9 users can use watch app, but iOS8 users can't.